# Error Syntax error on token ";", , expected - Minecraft

Tags: java, mod-rewrite, syntax, minecraft

I am creating a Minecraft mod, and I am getting the error Syntax error on token ";", , expected on this line

```
public static Block BasaltSmooth;
```

Here is the code :

```
package BitBox.Mods.BetterEgg;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.Init;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.PreInit;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.network.NetworkMod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.LanguageRegistry;

@Mod(modid = "BitBox's Mod", name = "BitBoxMod", version = "V0.1")
@NetworkMod(clientSideRequired = true, serverSideRequired = false)
public class mainClass {
    // Initialization

    //tabs
    public static Item BitBoxTabIcon;

    //items

    //blocks
    public static Block BasaltSmooth;

    BasaltSmooth = new BitBoxBlock(500, Material.rock)
        .setHardness(0.5F)
        .setUnlocalizedName("Basalt Stone")
        .setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);

    public static CreativeTabs bitBoxTab;

    @EventHandler
    public void load(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        LanguageRegistry.addName(BasaltSmooth, "Basalt Stone");
        MinecraftForge.setBlockHarvestLevel(BasaltSmooth, "pickaxe", 0);
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(BasaltSmooth, "Basalt Stone");
    }

    public mainClass() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions - variables should be in lower camel case and classes in upper camel case.

Comment: Always provide correctly indented code, be kind towards our eyes! This time I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You cant do like this

```
public static Block BasaltSmooth;

BasaltSmooth = new BitBoxBlock(500, Material.rock).setHardness(0.5F).setUnlocalizedName("Basalt            
 Stone").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
```

Do like this

```
public static Block BasaltSmooth = new BitBoxBlock(500, Material.rock).setHardness(0.5F).setUnlocalizedName("Basalt            
 Stone").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prabhakaran's answer should help you with instantiating the Block correctly, Minecraft can be picky at times. Howerever, another issue is that you should register it in the FML PreInit phase:

---

```
class{
create block with properties here.

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        Register block with game here
    }
}
```